# Artifactory giving 404 for rpm repository

Tags: artifactory, rpm

After adding a new package to our RPM repo in Artifactory we started getting the following error.  We tried running the Recalculate Index and tried removing the new package but neither have worked.  We have also tried `yum clean all` on the hosts.

I tried manually created that file with an old copy of the metadata but then I run into checksum issues.  Anyone run into this or have a fix?

```
https://artifactrepo.domain.com/artifactory/ttapps-rpm-local-2/repodata/084ab80f88ffcc4c0b25d41966e0b8802d465914-primary.xml.gz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly possible that you are running into this bug - [RTFACT-15974](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15974)

Note the mentioned workaround and that it was already fixed in version 5.11.0

Comment: That looks like it, we are on an older version

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the entire repometada folder in the repo and then running recalculate index fix the issue